# iOS: Changing annotation image back to normal when user touches any object

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, annotations, mkmapview

I have this annotation that changes images to a whitepin when selected. This works very well, but now I need to make it turn back to bluepin.png when user touches any object. I tried accomplishing this by putting a method in the diddeselect delegate, but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

```
 - (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)aMapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
   {      id<MKAnnotation> annotation = view.annotation;


 if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[Annotation class]]) {
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"whitepin.png"]];
     view.image = img;

   }}
```

edit: if it helps, put this method in the diddeselect method causes the same effect where the annotation stays white (whitepin.png)

Comment: I have the same problem. And I'm not getting any leads yet to it. Have you fixed your problem? Hmmm